# Wrap items in an array with a character

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array `[1, 5, 20, 17, 6, 12, 13, 20, 1, 14, 20]`.

Whenever the element of the array is equal to 20 I would like to wrap it with an asterisk on either side like this `[1, 5, *20*, 17, 6, 12, 13, *20*, 1 , 14, *20*]`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Arrays [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to modify the elements of the array. `elem` is each element and `i` is the respective index. We are using `forEach` to modify the existing array. Since this is what you desired..

```js
let arr = [1, 5, 20, 17, 6, 12, 13, 20, 1, 14, 20]

arr.forEach((elem, i) => {
  if (elem === 20) {
    arr[i] = "*20*"
  }
})

console.log(arr)



function rollDice(max, times, bonus) {
        var rolls = [1, 5, 20, 17, 6, 12, 13, 20, 1, 14, 20];
        rolls.forEach((elem, i) => { if (elem === 20) { rolls[i] = "twenty" } });
        for (var i = 0; times > i; i++)
        { 
            max = Math.floor(max);
            rolls.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + 1 | + parseInt(bonus));
        }
        console.log(rolls);
} 
    
rollDice(20, 5);
```

Comment: I'm with you on this one, not sure why someone down-voted.  From what the OP says, to me he wants the original array changing.  So `forEach` is indeed the correct choice, `map` would be if the OP wanted a none destructive copy.  And I can't see anywhere in the OP's question were he's asking for a new array..

Comment: @Keith: Thanks for the comment! :D

Comment: @AshishRanjan I really appreciate the help but I cant seem to get it working, this is the code I have

`function rollDice(max, times, bonus) {
    var rolls = [];
        rolls.forEach((elem, i) => {
            if (elem === 20) {
            rolls[i] = "twenty"
      }
    })
    for (var i = 0; times > i; i++) {
        max = Math.floor(max);

        rolls.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + 1 | + parseInt(bonus));
    }
    console.log(rolls);
}
rollDice(20, 5);
`
Do you know why it isn't working?

Edit: sorry about the formatting, comments don't like code blocks

Comment: @firewire167: shoouldn't `rolls` have values in it?? See my updated answer??

Comment: @AshishRanjan Rolls.push generates the array and sends it to the rolls variable, but I actually managed to fix it on my own, I just had to move the forEach loop under my for loop and it works just fine, Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Thank you! And just noted.. you are not passing the `bonus` value, doing a `parseInt(bonus)` will result in `NaN`. Please also take care of that..

Answer (score 8):

You can use `map`

```js
let arr = [1, 5, 20, 17, 6, 12, 13, 20, 1, 14, 20]

let result = arr.map(o => o === 20 ? '*20*' : o);

console.log(result);
```

Doc: [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: @DanielA.White it only converts the 20s to strings..no other choice.

Comment: @SajjanSarkar i know i just want the OP to know.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are experiencing is that you need to convert the integer number into strings.  JavaScript has several ways to cleverly do this behind-the-scenes, but if you are still gaining an understanding of that, it's better to be explicit about what data types you start with (integers), and what data types you expect to end with (strings).

You transform the array, "mapping" over each item, transforming it to a string, and then if the string matches "20", you add the asterisks.

```
const start_array = [1, 5, 20, 17, 6, 12, 13, 20, 1, 14, 20];

const new_array = start_array.map((integer) => {
  let number_string = integer.toString();
  if (number_string === "20") {
    number_string = "*" + number_string + "*";
  }
  return number_string;
})

console.log(new_array);
```